# dotnet ef command no longer works after upgrading to Visual Studio 16.3.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli, entity-framework-core-3.0

This happened at home first, so I thought maybe it was an issue with my desktop PC at home. But now that I am back at work, I tried the upgrade and got the same thing.

**Screenshot before upgrade**

[image: dotnet ef command]

**Screenshot after upgrading Visual Studio**

[image: dotnet ef command]

The error I get is:

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
>
> Possible reasons for this include:
>
> - You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
> - You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
> - You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Any ideas on why this happens? And how do I get back the `dotnet ef` command. I mean must have been in the `$PATH` previously, otherwise it wouldn't have worked before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [breaking change in Entity Framework Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#the-ef-core-command-line-tool-dotnet-ef-is-no-longer-part-of-the-net-core-sdk):

> The EF Core command-line tool, dotnet ef, is no longer part of the .NET Core SDK.
>
> ...
>
> Starting in 3.0, the .NET SDK does not include the dotnet ef tool, so before you can use it you have to explicitly install it as a local or global tool.

You need to install the [Entity Framework Core Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ef). To install it globally, run this on the command line:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Comment: What if I have an older project (on Core 2.0) that I need to enhance.  Can I add an `ef migration` to a 2.0 project with the 3.0 SDK's tool?

Comment: @Grandizer Why use the 3.0 SDK though? Just use 2.x that matches your code, you will have it installed anyway.

Comment: @DavidG - perfect, but I am getting this `Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.` and trying to figure it out.

Comment: @DavidG I am find to use the 2.x but it is not obvious how to force it to access that version based on the above error message.  This was my command to add a migration `dotnet ef migrations add EmployeeUtilization -s ..\Almanac` which has worked for the entire project until I started working on a .NET Core 3 project and installed that SDK.

Comment: So reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) I did `dotnet tool install --local --version 2.0 dotnet-ef` from the base of my repo.  That worked!  Did this prior, but not sure if I needed to: `dotnet new tool-manifest`