# How to properly install dotnet ef on Ubuntu?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ubuntu

I'm trying to install [dotenet ef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) on `Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS`.

First, I've installed the tool globally:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

As it was not working, then I added this PATH reference to my dotnet tools folder on my `.bashrc` file:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"`

As suggested here: [Cannot find command 'dotnet ef'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862089/cannot-find-command-dotnet-ef)

Yet when I try to run `dotnet ef`, I get this error message:

```sh
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Interestingly if I try to install it again I'm informed it is already installed.

```sh
Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.
```

But if I try to list my installed tools with `dotnet tool list` I get an empty result:

```sh
Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.
```

I have also checked my `~/.dotnet/tools/` folder and it is empty.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you use `snap install` to install the dotnet sdk? If so, try `sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet`. Might not help but will at least narrow down the problem

Comment: @jandrew I'm not sure if I did. Is there any way I can be sure if I did it or not?

Comment: Well, how did you install the .NET SDK on your Ubuntu machine? I'm guessing it was either through one of the package managers (`sudo apt-get`, etc.) or you manually installed it?

Comment: I can't remember how I did it, is there any way I can check on how it was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu. I had installed dotnet manually. For some reason dotnet-ef looks for dotnet in "/usr/share/dotnet". So I had to install the dotnet-sdk exactly in the directory "/usr/share/dotnet", change the PATH accordingly and also set DOTNET_ROOT to this directory. Then dotnet-ef also worked.

Btw: You can set the installation path of dotnet-ef manually by --tool-path "$HOME/.dotnet/tools" if --global does not work.

Comment: This lead me to finding I had a /usr/share/dotnet that was empty and recreating it as a symlink to my $HOME/.dotnet folder

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution.

Add the following to the .bashrc/.zshrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"
```

Answer (score 0):

While using Fish, use `fish_add_path $HOME/.dotnet/tools/` after installing ef globally.