# VS Code terminal does not recognize dotnet ef

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I get an error while running the below command on VS Code terminal

```
dotnet ef -h
```

and here is the error:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

But everything is OK on Windows's cmd.
Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862089/cannot-find-command-dotnet-ef/56876020) I'm sure `PATH` has defined correctly in Environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add EntityFrameworkCore Tools package.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```